# How to organise QWidgets into a mosaic?

Tags: layout, qt4, pyqt4

I would like to create a Qwidget with a large number of square QPushButtons. I would like those buttons to be organised into a mosaic layout. Whenever the window is resized, the mosaic widget should be resized and the buttons re-ordered accordingly to fill in the width. Buttons that cannot fit within the area, can be viewed by scrolling the widget vertically.

Is there a Qt4 Layout that allows me to do this easily? What is the best / easiest way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [the flow layout (from Qt examples)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-flowlayout.html) inside a [resizable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) `QScrollArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`QGridLayout`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QGridLayout.html) in a `QScrollArea`.

Comment: The QGridLayout won't rearrange horizontal items vertically on a new line when out of space.